# Display data from database without Gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to create a page where a list of doctors will appear from my database. But without using the Gridview. I want to display the informations as in the image below. Please help me.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k8A2.jpg)

Comment: You can make a Listview either through Gridview Settings or directly as a sepperate view. After that you can style the list like you need it. At least thats the case with web pages.

Comment: Also please post the image directly in your question and not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vb.net...you must use repeater. Other way is iterate data with a for.
Doc for repeater:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb

Doc for iterate lists:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement